# Twilio Data Only API

Tags: android, mobile, twilio

I'm working on an Android application.  Is there a way to limit Twilio so that it only works while connected to wifi?  I know my code can listen for the device to lose wifi and then cancel the call, but we do not want Twilio to work without data in anyway.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Talked to Twilio support and there is no way to do this, as of Oct 12, 2020.